# R: data frame - How to add up values and consolidate duplicate values?

Tags: r, plyr

I am looking for a way to add the following data on transfusion of blood products:

```
MRN  Product Transfusion.Date Volume
001  PRBC    2004-12-02       50
002  PRBC    2004-12-02       50
002  PRBC    2004-12-02      100
003  FFP     2004-12-03        1 
003  FFP     2004-12-03        1
003  FFP     2004-12-04        1
```

So what I want to do is add the volumes, whenever the *same* patient (MRN) received the *same* product on the *same* day. In all other cases I would like to keep it separate.

```
MRN  Product Transfusion.Date Volume
001  PRBC    2004-12-02       50
002  PRBC    2004-12-02       150 
003  FFP     2004-12-03        2
003  FFP     2004-12-04        1
```

I think that using ddply (and summarize?) should work and I have found solutions for similar problems, but I have no idea how to solve this....

Comment: @RichardScriven Yes I did do some searching, but I did not know how to phrase the problem and did not use the term aggregation (did not know that it was called that). Will do.

Comment: In `dplyr` you could do `group_by(df, MRN, Product, Transfusion.Date) %>% summarise(Volume = sum(Volume))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aggregate(Volume~., data=df, sum)

 MRN Product Transfusion.Date Volume
1   1    PRBC       2004-12-02     50
2   2    PRBC       2004-12-02    150
3   3     FFP       2004-12-03      2
4   3     FFP       2004-12-04      1
```

Comment: Or a little more explicit: `aggregate(Volume ~ MRN + Product + Transfusion.Date, data = df, FUN = sum)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
```

it can be done in one line as

```
DT[, sum(Volume), by = list(MRN, Product, Transfusion.Date)]
```

The second argument (`j` term) in brackets is the function you want to perform, and the `by` determines how to subset the data. Results for your example:

```
   MRN Product Transfusion.Date  V1
1:   1    PRBC       2004-12-02  50
2:   2    PRBC       2004-12-02 150
3:   3     FFP       2004-12-03   2
4:   3     FFP       2004-12-04   1
```